# How to make a free space around a Frameless QWidget?

Tags: qt, resize, qwidget, qt5.5

I have made a custom Window in Qt and now facing to resizing problem.

I want a free space around my `QWidget` (`Qt::FramelessWindowHint`) so i can process the Mouse Hover+Leave+press+release events in that area and in this events i change the cursor shape and resizing the widget.
(I don't want mouseEvent for widget but for that space)

How could i get such area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `QWidget` is added to a `QLayout` at some point. Then just ask the containing `QLayout` to reserve some free space around it's content by calling [setContentsMargins].

Example, you had:

```
QWidget* widget = new QWidget( parent );
parent->layout()->addWidget( widget );
```

Then, just add:

```
parent->layout()->setContentsMargins( 100,100,100,100 );
```

This will guarantee that `widget` has 100 pixels of empty area around it.

To be more generic, and it case you had no parent, you can create an intermediate `QWidget` like that:

You had:

```
QWidget* myWidget = new QWidget( NULL );
widget->show();
```

Just do:

```
QWidget* parentWithEmptySpaceBorder = new QWidget( NULL );
parentWithEmptySpaceBorder->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout() );
parentWithEmptySpaceBorder->layout()->setContentsMargins( 100,100,100,100 );

QWidget* myWidget = new QWidget( NULL );
parentWithEmptySpaceBorder->layout()->addWidget( myWidget );

parentWithEmptySpaceBorder->show();
```

Comment: @jpo38.Thanks but what about mouseEvents? can that layout receive mouseEvent? beacuase i need to process mouseEvent in that area

Comment: @IMAN4K: mouse events will be received by `parent`. It could be transmitted to `widget` by using `QObject::installEventFilter`.